# Nginx Kubernetes 404 Routing issue

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I am attempting to use nginx for my ingress controller and I am having something quite stupid that I cannot seem to figure out.  I deployed nginx via helm (through terraform) but it seems to have installed just fine.  I am seeing logging but getting a 404 error when trying to connect to a downstream service.   I can see the request in my nginx pod but get this error:

```
"HEAD /fibonacci/23 HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "curl/7.87.0" 89 0.002 [ingress-nginx-fibonacci-service-80] [] 10.244.0.7:80 0 0.003 404 54bc7726c7cc80e4090a77d01254ca10
```

I have tried to setup my routes in all ways that I can think of and still not sure why it is unable to find my service.  I have also confirmed that when I port-forward directly to the port then my service returns fine (via cURL) I am sure that I have configured something incorrectly but having trouble seeing what that is.   Below is my ingress routes and my service definition.

```
Ingress:
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "example" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
   
  metadata {
    name = "fibonacci"
    namespace = "ingress-nginx"
  }
  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "nginx"
    rule {
      http {
        path {
          path = "/"
          path_type = "Prefix"
          backend {
            service {
              name = "fibonacci-service"
              port {
                number = 80
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my service Definition

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "fibonacci-service"
    namespace = "ingress-nginx"
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = "fibonacci-hello-world"
    }
    session_affinity = "ClientIP"
    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 80
    }

    type = "ClusterIP"
  }
}
```

Any help (or second set of eyes) would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you share response of describing the service, and are you sure your application is listening on 80, if so login to the pod and try running a curl command for the endpoint you are trying to access.

Comment: In the ingress definition please  mention it as “paths” under “http” object instead of “path”.   It should be paths and under that it will be path.